# How to add marker to google map in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to add just one marker when tap on map and return the value of position it stands on

how can I do this ?

**NOTE :**  `GoogleMap` doesn't have `onTap`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library for google map https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter and also it has on tap on the marker onTap.

```
Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId("id"), // a string for marker unique id
    position: LatLng(lat, long), // lat and long doubles
    onTap: () {
      //this is what you're looking for!
    }
)
```